# MFC window fields like buttons and check boxes are in disabled state on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, compatibility, compatibility-mode

MFC window fields like buttons and check boxes are in disabled state on windows 7 machine. However this works fine on a Windows XP machine.

Please do note that when we enable compatibility options for executable and choose the compatibility mode as Windows XP (service pack 3) the buttons and checkboxes are enabled back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have identified the main problem, on windows 7 machine the logged in user has different set of privileges, which was not matching with the Administrative resulting in the above problem. Please make sure the logged in user has sufficient privileges to overcome this problem